# Eclipse- Launch configuration JUnitCore references non-existing project xxx

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I made it a java project and I am trying to insert a existing project, but I can't run it. 
[Here is a picture of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoJI2.png)
I need help to set this up property and solve the problem.
Thanks, Ash

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the other project to your current project's build path. Right click on your project>Build Path>Configure Build path>Projects Tab>Add